# How to specify multiple matches in minimatch

Tags: minimatch

I need to target specific files using minimatch (in TypeDoc exclude - I don't need tests and some other files).

I need to exclude all files from `/test` directory and all `index.ts` in all directories

Tried `**/+(index.ts|**/test/*.ts)` but it doesn't work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try `**/!(test)/!(index)*.ts` using [globster.xyz](https://globster.xyz/?q=**%2F!(test)%2F!(index)*.ts&f=%2Fmyapp%2Freadme.ts%2C%2Fmyapp%2Ftest%2Fstaging.ts%2C%2Fmyapp%2Ftest%2Fproduction.ts%2C%2Fmyapp%2Fsrc%2Fservices%2Findex.ts%2C%2Fmyapp%2Fsrc%2Fservices%2Ftimezone.ts%2C%2Fmyapp%2Fsrc%2Fcontrollers%2Findex.ts%2C%2Fmyapp%2Fsrc%2Fcontrollers%2Fuser.module.ts%2C%2Fmyapp%2Fassets%2Fa.ts%2C%2Fmyapp%2Fassets%2Fb.ts%2C%2Fmyapp%2Fassets%2Fc.ts)